What is the actual meaning of Derivative in Multivariable Calculus?
We say that Function(Let's take R^(2)->R) is Differentiable when that Limit exists then we
To check if a function ( f(x, y) ) is differentiable at a point ( (a, b) ), we use the following limit:
$$
\lim_{(h, k) \to (0, 0)} \frac{f(a + h, b + k) - f(a, b) - f_x(a, b) \cdot h - f_y(a, b) \cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}} = 0
$$
where:

( f x(a, b) ) and ( f y(a, b) ) are the partial derivatives of ( f ) with respect to ( x ) and ( y )

Then we say the value of Derivative at that point or Total Derivative is (f x(a,b)),f y(a,b))
What do we actually mean by Total Derivative Graphically (as in R->R it means Tangent) ?
As the Derivative of the single valued Function is an Vector.
Also what is the dimension (R^(m)->R(n)) of Derivative Function (in this case i.e  from R^(2)->R)and explain why it differs from Original Function?

The derivative should be the linear transformation acting between tangent spaces (suitably translated to hit the origin).  Hence, it is naturally a matrix when you're in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What do you mean by "it differs from [the] original function"?

This information is on innumerable sites on the web.  This question should be closed.

The proper definition of the derivative in higher dimensions is the following:
The derivative of $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x$ is a linear map $Df(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies
$$
\lim_{h\to0\in\mathbb{R}^m}~\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h}{\|h\|}=0.
$$
Notice here that $h$ and $x$ are vectors. A linear map from $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ most naturally takes the form of a $n\times m$ matrix. Such a matrix multiplies $m$-vectors and returns $n$-vectors, just like the original function $f$. We can rearrange the above limit to see that the derivative is defined as sort of a best linear approximation, just like in $1$ dimension. That is,
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + Df(x)h + \epsilon(h),
$$
where $\epsilon(h)$ is some error that satisfies $\lim_{h\to 0}~\frac{\epsilon(h)}{\|h\|}=0$. If $f$ has a Taylor series, we know this error is typically quadratic in $h$, so this limit is satisfied.
Now for how the derivative differs from the original function, it does so in a somewhat subtle way. Notice that for each poitn $x$, we have a potentially different linear map. Just like how in $1$ dimension, we may have a different slope at each point $x$. Here there are more variables to keep track of. If you want to specifically track every input and output, it would be more accurate to say that $Df:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$, since it takes in a point $x$ and a direction $h$, both in $\mathbb{R}^m$. This can be confusing, so the key point to remember is that at a fixed point $(x)$, $f$ and $Df(x)$ have the same input and output spaces. The makes sense, since $Df(x)$ can only be an approximation of $f$ if they have compatible domains and ranges. The story becomes more complicated once you move beyond the standard Euclidiean vector spaces, but this should help to clarify the case here.
